# How to integrate Google Analytics in Android app

Tags: android, google-analytics

Hi I am trying to integrate the Google Analytics but I am not able to find any analytics data that shows on the Google Analytics Account of mine. I am using the link mention below:-

[developers.google.com link 1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/)

[some link 1](http://antonioleiva.com/lead-android-app-success-google-analytics-part-1/)

[some link 2](http://antonioleiva.com/lead-your-android-app-to-success-with-google-analytics-part-2/?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=5b39a44e4b-Android_Weekly_73&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-5b39a44e4b-337823725)

[developer.google link 2](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#manifest)

But I am not able to get the result, nor the correct path/way or proper and Detailed Tutorial for how to integrate the Google Analytics in android app.

My code is as follows:-

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GoogleAnalytics tracker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         // Get tracker.
        Tracker t = ((AnalyticsHelper) MainActivity.this.getApplication()).getTracker(
            TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
     // Set the dispatch period in seconds.
        GAServiceManager.getInstance().setLocalDispatchPeriod(8);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
     // Set the dispatch period in seconds.
        GAServiceManager.getInstance().setLocalDispatchPeriod(8);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
    }
}
```

My Analytics Helper class is as follows:-

```
public class AnalyticsHelper extends Application {

     // The following line should be changed to include the correct property id.
    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-xxxxxxxx-x"; // My Property id.

    public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
        ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    public AnalyticsHelper()
    {
        super();
    }

    synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(LogLevel.VERBOSE);
            Tracker t = null;
            if(trackerId==TrackerName.APP_TRACKER){
                t= analytics.getTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
            }
                 mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
                }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
}
```

And my analytics xml file in xml directory is as follows:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

     <!--  The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-xxxxxxxx-X</string>

   <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

  <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

</resources>
```

Any help will be heart-fully welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start by using the v4 of the sdk not the legacy version.  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/  also it can take 24 - 48 hours for your data to start showing up.  How long did you wait?

Comment: @DalmTo well I just waited for 1-3 hours. well now will wait for 24 to 48 hours and then see will it show anything. Thanks.

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks it had worked after I waited for 24 hours. Sorry for late replying...

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela I'm trying to implement Google Analytics v4, but I am having a problem when I write GoogleAnalytics analytics = .. . Android Studio does not know what it is and give me error. Has happened to you? I imported google play service properly. I asked a question here on stack, check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254017/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-googleanalytics-v4

Comment: @Ilario had you included the Google Analytics Library File?

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela to integrate Google Analytics v4 should be enough to have built google-play service. is not it? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: @Ilario If you are using Android Studio you must add Proguard to your gradle.build file's build types.
Refer the links given below:- 
https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html


http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard

Comment: Tracker t = ((AnalyticsHelper)  gives me class cast exception, what should i do?

Comment: @Salmaan are you only trying to track your App on google play store? I have one small bit of code for dong so.

Comment: Thanks @PravinsinghWaghela i achieved what i needed without doing so...

Comment: @Salmaan That's Great. Well I had edited My Question for the Answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well the above code given in the Question works well.
All you need to do is after setting your code and adding the Jar file [Download Google Analytics Jar file](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)  to your Lib. just wait for 24 to 48 hours. and it would show all the events and analytic for the App you had registered.

### **Edited Answer:-**

Once You had Created your Google Analytic account and Downloaded the Jar file, Add the Jar file in your **lib** folder of your Application

**Google Analytic Implementation:-**

Well For Analytic Part You Just need the ***analytic.xml*** file to be included in your values folder which is mentioned in the Question.

Then define `private EasyTracker easyTracker = null;` in your ***MainActivity***.

And now in your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method just write the following lines of Code. Well you can also write the following code for any Listners e.g. on any Button Click.

```
    /*
    *For Google Analytics...
    */
    easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(MainActivity.this); // It Tracks your Activity...
    easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("SomeValue(StoryPage)",
            "SomeMoreValue(AuthorName) , "SomeMoreValueAgain(StoryTitle)", null).build()); //This line creates the event for keeping logs and other Analytical stuffs concerned to this Activity of Application...
//In the above example we had Tracked the session for the MainActivity and also Analysed how many time this activity was opened, which Author story and which Story was read.
```

Now in your `onStart()` Method, just write the following code, it starts the Tracking and Analytics session for your Activity.

```
EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
```

And now in your `onStop()` Method, just write the following code, it will close or stop the Tracking session for this activity.

```
EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
```

Now you are able to Track and Analysis your Application and Activities in It.

Comment: it gives class cast exception on line:
 // Get tracker.
        Tracker t = ((AnalyticsHelper) MainActivity.this.getApplication()).getTracker(
            TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
     // Set the dispatch period in seconds.
        GAServiceManager.getInstance().setLocalDispatchPeriod(8);

Comment: @ArslanAhmad  are you only trying to track your App on google play store? I have one small bit of code for dong so.

Comment: @ArslanAhmad Just check the Answer, I had Edited it now.

Answer (score 2):

I have detailed the steps for integrating Google Analytics into an existing app [here](http://www.mackenziesoftware.com/2015/01/integrating-google-analytics-into.html). When I publish a new app I always go back to these instructions which work well.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply mate.

Comment: Is there any way to show these data on the mobile app?

Answer (score 2):

1. Fisrt we have to create google analytics track id [Goolge analytics sign in and enable api and get track id](https://www.google.com/analytics/#?modal_active=none)
2. After that put that track id in below .xml code

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
<string name="ga_trackingId">"place your track id"</string>
<string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
<screenName name="com.aquadeals.seller.HomeMainActivity">DashBoard Screen</screenName>
```

3. After that we can change manifest file very important to add this code below
**Add permissions**

4.**Change your application name to google analytics class name example"MyApplication.java"**

```
 <application
    android:name=".app.MyApplication"
```

5. After that add services for sending and receiving broadcast events using internet

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service           android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
    <receiver       android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
```

6. Before this manifest changes first add this two classes in your app

public final class AnalyticsTrackers
{

```
public enum Target {APP,}
private static AnalyticsTrackers sInstance;
public static synchronized void initialize(Context context)
{
    if (sInstance != null) 
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Extra call to initialize analytics trackers");
    }
    sInstance = new AnalyticsTrackers(context);
}
public static synchronized AnalyticsTrackers getInstance() 
{
    if (sInstance == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Call initialize() before getInstance()");
    }
    return sInstance;
}
private final Map<Target, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<Target, Tracker>();
private final Context mContext;
private AnalyticsTrackers(Context context)
{
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
}
public synchronized Tracker get(Target target)
{
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(target)) 
    {
        Tracker tracker;
        switch (target)
        {
            case APP:
                tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mContext).newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unhandled analytics target " + target);
        }
        mTrackers.put(target, tracker);
    }
    return mTrackers.get(target);
}
```

}

**And Add this AnalyticsApplication.java**

```
public class AnalyticsApplication extends MultiDexApplication
```

{

```
private Tracker mTracker;
private static AnalyticsApplication mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
    AnalyticsTrackers.initialize(this);
    AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance().get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
}

synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker()
{
    if (mTracker == null)
    {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(AnalyticsApplication.this);

        mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
    }
    return mTracker;
}

public synchronized Tracker getGoogleAnalyticsTracker()
{
    AnalyticsTrackers analyticsTrackers = AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance();
    return analyticsTrackers.get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
}

public void trackEvent(String category, String action, String label)
{
    Tracker t = getDefaultTracker();
    t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(category).setAction(action).setLabel(label).build());
}

public static synchronized AnalyticsApplication getInstance()
{
    return mInstance;
}

public void trackScreenView(String screenName)
{
    Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();
    t.setScreenName(screenName);
    t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).dispatchLocalHits();
}


public void trackException(Exception e)
{
    if (e != null) {
        Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();
        t.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
             .setDescription( new StandardExceptionParser(this, null)
             .getDescription(Thread.currentThread().getName(), e))
     .setFatal(false)
     .build()
        );
    }
}
```

}

7. And last we can add code in your mainactivity.java class or you required classes
   **Initialize Step1**

   AnalyticsApplication application1;

   private Tracker mTracker;

   **Step :2**

   application1 = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();

   mTracker = application1.getDefaultTracker();

if you run this code in google analytics showing screen name you mentioned in xml.

**Step :3 Add this code for track event**

```
mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()

                .setCategory("DashBoard ")

                    .setAction("View Bookings Pressed")

                    .build());
```

**Step :4 Track exception behaviour code add in you catch block**

```
 catch (Exception e) {
         **   AnalyticsApplication.getInstance().trackException(e);**
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Happy coding..

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of where the tracking shows on the dashboard? I implemented tracking but I can't see where the data shows up.

Comment: Once check this url https://www.google.com/analytics/#?modal_active=none

Comment: Is extending Application mandatory for Creating a Tracker instance ?

Comment: @vgokul129 I think its required

Comment: @VenkateshNani: Any specific theory to claim so.

Comment: @vgokul129: Please follow firebase analytics easy to integrate compare with google analytics above link