# Google Analytics on Android gives avg session duration: 00:00:00

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

i'm using google analytics on Android and it gives me a lot of **avg session duration: 00:00:00**

**please note that i'm not using "ga_autoActivityTracking" and i have more than one activity**

here's my code

***build.gradle***

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
```

***Application class***

```
Tracker mTracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).newTracker(R.xml.tracker);
```

***tracker.xml***

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
    <!-- Replace placeholder GA tracking Id with a real one. -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-1111111-1</string>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

    <!-- 1800 seconds is 30 minutes, which is the default.
        Included explicitly for ease of tweaking. -->
    <integer name="ga_dispatchInterval">1800</integer>

    <bool name="ga_debug">false</bool>
</resources>
```

***i send screenviews on onStart function or onPageSelected within a viewpager***

```
public static void sendScreenView(String screenName) {
        if (canSend()) {
            mTracker.setScreenName(screenName);
            mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder()
                    .setCustomDimension(COUNTRY_INDEX, getCountryCode()).build());
            Timber.i(TAG, "Screen View recorded: " + screenName);
        } else {
            Timber.i(TAG, "Screen View NOT recorded (analytics disabled or not ready).");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

What is your Bounce Rate? If it is ~100%, there may not be any problem with your code, and instead with the UX/UI of your app.

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't already, try setting auto activity tracking to true.

```
tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
```

Usually you do this in a class that extends Application.

Answer (score -1):

try this tutorial where you can track manually activities or fragments

full source code and step by step instruction: [click hare](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-google-analytics-example/)

Answer (score -1):

Refer the link given below, its for `Eclipse` but i think it can help you to solve your problem.

[How to integrate Google Analytics in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782901/how-to-integrate-google-analytics-in-android-app/26010301#26010301)