# Integrating Google Analytics in an existing Android app via Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics, analytics

so after taking a painful amount of time I was able to create my first android app! But now I want to integrate google analytics so that I can keep a track of how users are interacting with my app. I have tried a few sources;

[Link 1](http://www.mackenziesoftware.com/2015/01/integrating-google-analytics-into.html)

(I am completely stumped at the 3rd step mentioned in Link1)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782901/how-to-integrate-google-analytics-in-android-app)

[Link 3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)

I failed to complete the steps given in the above mentioned links and now my question is can somebody recommend the easiest way for a newbie to integrate google analytics in an existing android app. Even if i can get a couple of event tracked it would be mean success and I am sure I will be able to build from there.

Comment: see this tutorial will helpful http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-integrating-google-analytics-v4/

Comment: google analytics is good but i have recently discovered fabric by twitter, its really easy to integrate into your app and it has a great web interface & mobile app. https://get.fabric.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part you are stumped on is adding the meta-data tags?

You just need to add the quoted lines inside the "Application" section of your Android Manifest.

```
<Application>

All of your activities etc...

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
           android:resource="@xml/global_tracker"/>

</Application>
```

Personally I would use [Google's own instructions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)  as any you may find on a blog etc could be out of date.